# Extract character between two specified characters of a string using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a string and want to extract the numbers between the character 'w' and 's'. The positions of the the characters vary between different strings.

For example:

```
s = '1w12s01'
```

desired result: `'12'`

and

```
s = '102w22s21'
```

desired result: `'22'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function strfind will do this easily enough.  This will work as long as the number is always directly between a 'w' and and 's', both are only in the target string once, and the number you're after is the only thing between those two characters.

```
s = '102w22s21';
r = s((strfind(s, 'w')+1):(strfind(s, 's')-1));
```

Answer (score 3):

It can also be done using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) with [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regexp(s,'(?<=w).*(?=s)','match')
```

Comment: Useful links those! And smart solution too. +1

Comment: You can avoid the complexity of the lookarounds with this: `regexp(s,'.*w(.*)s.*','tokens','once')`.

Comment: Thanks! I never got the hang of the `'tokens'` option, but it's very useful here

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
    e = extractBetween(s,'w','s');